# How to include javascript file in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, galileo

Actually I am a new user of eclipse....
I am integrating a library into my web application.i am stuck over the problem of including javascript file into my application...can anyone help me on how to do it in eclipse..
i use e

Comment: What type of web application..?.ex: if you use ruby on rails just copy your js files in you root directory manually (public/javascripts/). So, tell me which technology are you using.

Comment: Actually application is simple implemetation of class schedule maker.....i am trying to integrate spellchecker library into it....

Comment: Ok, np. Mostly IDE's not import the files to correct location. Because, they only provide the development purpose only. bcz, each project, jsp, android, ROR and PHP framework, etc.. have unique file and folder structure. So you should copy/create the file manually. So, if you'r using jsp, you should use any one server. An example, if you use tomcat. just copy your jar or js file in your root/www/ folder..

Comment: I got what you want to say and actually i have tried this and have already got the jar files in root directory of apache plus also in the WEB-INF/lib of eclipse workspace....but there is javascript file that also needs to be included and like eclipse has given location for all other types of file like .jsp in web-contents , .java in src....so i was wondering what is the location for javascript files....???

Comment: @mr.Black..Sorry for got to tag you...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

some reference maybe help: [eclipse forum about including javascript file](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&goto=360495&#page_top)

Comment: What's that.. ?. Please post correct answers only. Don't put anonymous links.

Comment: @Abhimanyu. No, the link is forum of eclipse site. But, the answer is not correct.